# How to use a word mail merge with a password protected Access file

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, password-protection, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I am trying to use Word mail merge to send emails and retrieve all the data like name and title from an Access database however, the database is password protected and I keep on getting errors saying the password is wrong even though it is the correct password.

I have searched all over the internet and nothing seems to be working. In addition, I have tried allowing exclusive access when making the connection and have tried different connection types and nothing is working.

Comment: Review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mail-merge-on-a-password-protected-access-database/c2bfe4ec-ea6c-4287-9249-37a060e9d731 and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-automate-word-mail-merge-with-password/7250800e-0ffb-4ff3-ab8a-4ce8ef655a11

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Please can you add it as a response so I can give it a green tick.

Comment: Exactly what worked? You can post an answer and accept it.

Comment: But then you won't get the reputation you deserve.

Comment: Not a concern for me. Not really interested in making effort to build and verify code. You can simply post your working code in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in this forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mail-merge-on-a-password-protected-access-database/c2bfe4ec-ea6c-4287-9249-37a060e9d731

> a. in Word, go to File->Options->Advanced->General (near the bottom of
> the Advanced options)
>
> b. check "Confirm file format conversion on Open"
>
> c. re-open your Word Mail Merge Main Document
>
> d. go through the process of connecting to the Access database again
> (e.g. Mailings tab->Select Recipients->Use Existing List
>
> e. Once you have selected the .mdb or .accdb, you should see an
> additional dialog box titled "Confirm Data Source". For an ACCDB, only
> one option will be displayed ("OLE DB Database Files"). In that case,
> check "Show All". A number of other options should appear.
>
> f. locate and select the option titled "MS Access Databases via DDE
> (*.mdb;*.mde)", then click OK.
>
> g. If the database is already open in Access, you should now see a
> dialogue box with a list of tables/queries. Otherwise, Word tries to
> start Access if it is not already running, then asks Access to open
> the database. At this point, Access should prompt you for the database
> password. However, it is possible that the dialogue box will appear
> behind Word, so if you do not see it quickly, alt-tab to the Access
> application and respond to the dialogue box. Then you should see the
> list of tables/queries and you can proceed.